# Angular + Ionic - Using ionic components returns 'not a known element'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I just created an app using Ionic and Angular, but I always get the following error, it doesn't matter if I put the html into the ionic generated "pages" folder or in my newly made page.

Ionic version 5.4.16
Angular version 11.2.13

[image]

This is my LoginPage html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>OSCheckin</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<div>
  <div class="d-flex h-100">
    <div class="m-auto w-75">
      <IonItem>
          <IonLabel>Email</IonLabel>
          <IonInput value="" placeholder="Ex.: joao.silva@prefeitura.org.br" type="email"></IonInput>
      </IonItem>
      <IonItem>
          <IonLabel>Senha</IonLabel>
          <IonInput value="" placeholder="*********"></IonInput>
      </IonItem>
      <IonButton onClick="" expand="block">Entrar</IonButton>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is my login module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { LoginPageRoutingModule } from './login-routing.module';

import { LoginPage } from './login.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    LoginPageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [LoginPage]
})
export class LoginPageModule {}
```

And this is my AppModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    IonicModule.forRoot(), 
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this was pretty basic, my mistake was that I was trying to use the components like the following:

```
<IonButton></IonButton>
<IonItem></IonItem>
etc
```

the correct was

```
<ion-button></ion-button>
<ion-item></ion-item>
etc
```

really can't believe I lost 2 hours on this

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll fix it by adding the angular common module with your ionic module

ie: AppModule.ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    CommonModule
```

Comment: Really hoped that this was the answer but it didn't make a diference :(

Comment: Just to make sure, you're adding CommonMOdule to each module.ts file (that also uses IonicMOdule)?

Comment: Yeah, I included it in every module.ts files that I could after you've suggested it, even the routing ones, but it didn't work, tried one by one btw.

I'll try creating another project with an older Angular version to check if I can make it work

Comment: Hey, it worked on Angular 9. I'll "report" this on the official forum.
Thx anyway mate ;)

Comment: You wont believe it........
I'm so mad with myself rn, the issue was that I was trying to use IonButton, IonItem, etc, the correct was ion-button, ion-item, etc